Laravel 10 - Testeo de rutas protegidas con Laravel Passport, no consigo logearme de forma fake para las pruebas
tengo este fichero :
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RouteAccessesAsEmployeeTest extends TestCase
{

    public function loginAsEmployee(){

        $employee = User::factory()->create();
        $employee->assignRole('Employee');
        $this->actingAs($employee,'web');
    }
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    public function test_employee_can_get_own_info(): void
    {

        $this->loginAsEmployee();
        $response = $this->post('/api/user/info');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}

La idea es tener una funcion en mi test que me loguee como empleado y asi poder probar las diferentes rutas, he empezado con el endpoint que me devuelve info sobre el propio usuario , si fuera un acceso normal necesitaria un token, pero al ser una prueba tengo que hacer un fake auth.
Estoy probando con $this->actingAs() pero me sigue fallando con permiso denegado
Tambien lo he probado con Passport::actingAs(...) pero nada
